# Visual studio doesn't use EBP when referring to stack variable

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2008

I have the following C++ code

```
int myFuncSum( int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result;
    result = myFuncSum(100, 200);
    return 0;
}
```

When I step through this in the disassembly window of Visual Studio 2008 on my Win7 Pro machine, I see the following for the call to myFuncSum():

```
int myFuncSum( int a, int b)
{
001C1000  push        ebp  
001C1001  mov         ebp,esp 
001C1003  push        ecx  
    int c;
    c = a + b;
001C1004  mov         eax,dword ptr [a] <--------------------
001C1007  add         eax,dword ptr [b] <--------------------
001C100A  mov         dword ptr [c],eax <--------------------
    return c;
001C100D  mov         eax,dword ptr [c] <--------------------
}
```

As I have indicated, the four lines that refer to the variables a, b and c refer to them as such, not as offsets relative to EBP.

Can anyone please suggest what I need to do to Visual Studio to get it to refer to them via EBP?  I have already disabled C++ optimisations in the project settings; without doing so I don't even get my function called.

Comment: It is already referring to them using `ebp` (or `esp`) but your disassembler was just trying to be helpful and turned that back to variable names for you. According to google, you can right click to bring up the context menu and uncheck `Show symbol names`.

Comment: I would also suggest in a function like this to just return the sum and skip creating the temporary in the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes of course; but this is a beginners' tutorial that I was following :)

Comment: Side note - there's a compiler command line option to turn off stack frames, which frees up ebp (it's still saved unless not used), and uses esp for stack based variables instead.

Comment: @rcgldr: thanks for that.  I've spent some time looking (hence the late reply to your comment) but I've been unable to find this option.  Can you tell me what it is, in both VC++ and gcc, if you know please?

Comment: @Wad - the option for Visual Studio is "omit frame pointers". The command line option is /Oy (VS2013 back to VC/C++ 4.0) . I don't know about gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disassembler is just trying to be helpful, not spamming you too much about irrelevant details.  Not entirely accidental, this syntax abbreviation is also permitted in inline assembly with the `__asm` keyword.

You can switch back-and-forth, right-click the disassembly window and untick Show Symbol Names.  Now you'll see the real machine code:

```
    c = a + b;
003613DE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
003613E1  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
003613E4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
    return c;
003613E7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
```